# How to select billing address for customer in IPP .net SDK 3

Tags: c#, sql, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I am able, using the new Intuit Partner Program version 3 SDK for `QBOE`, to specify a particular select query with `QueryService.ExecuteIdsQuery`.

I can execute the following and get back all information (including billing address) for all customers:

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER
```

I am also able to send the following and get back (for example) just the ID and `DisplayName` of all customers:

```
SELECT ID, DISPLAYNAME FROM CUSTOMER
```

However, an invalid query exception is thrown if I try to get just the ID and Billing address of all customers -- the following will NOT work:

```
SELECT ID, BILLADDR FROM CUSTOMER
```

The request is sent to `QBOE`, but the response complains that it doesn't know about `BillAddr`.

I think that under the hood, the `Select *` version is doing a join on a table of addresses, but joins are not allowed in the API that Intuit provides.

Is there any way to get select for billing address specifically, without doing a `Select *` to get the entire wide record for each customer?

Thanks in advance for all help....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According [docs](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/customer#Customer_Attributes) 'billAddr' is not filterable. You can't query only 'billAddr'.

Thanks

Comment: I don't need to filter on BillAddr.  Nor do I need only to query on it alone.... although the lack of being able to filter on it shouldn't address the ability to select it in a query.  What I am looking for is a way to have it returned in a thin result set of a query without having to get the entire wide result set of all attributes of a customer.

Comment: Yes Stephan. I understand the usecase. But currently it is not supported. In QBD V3(deprecated), you can atleast able to query elements like billAddr.City, billAddr.Line1 etc. But in QBO, this is not available yet. I'll update this post if I get info on its fix(or workaround/confirmation, if it is design choice). Thanks

Comment: Even though I wish this weren't the answer, it gets marked as the answer because it is true....